# Exponential Sheaf Sequence Jacobian Curve

Tags: geometry, manifolds, curves, exact-sequence, sheaf-cohomology

(1) Is it possible to consider the exponential sheaf sequence $0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{O} _{C}\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{C}^{\times} \rightarrow 0$ on a smooth irreducible projective plane curve $C$ (equipped with analytic topology?)?

(2) If yes, the cohomology sequence looks like (I guess)
$$0 \rightarrow H^{0}(\mathbb{Z}_{C}) \rightarrow H^{0}(\mathcal{O} _{C}) \rightarrow H^{0}(\mathcal{O}_{C}^{\times}) \rightarrow H^{1}(\mathbb{Z}_{C}) \rightarrow H^{1}(\mathcal{O} _{C}) \rightarrow H^{1}(\mathcal{O}_{C}^{\times}) \rightarrow H^{2}(\mathbb{Z}_{C}) \rightarrow H^{2}(\mathcal{O} _{C}) \rightarrow H^{2}(\mathcal{O}_{C}^{\times}) \rightarrow 0$$
Is it possible to determine the groups? I mean for example like $H^{1}(\mathcal{O}_{C}^{\times})=Pic(C)$. Is it related to the genus of $C$?

It may be a beginner's question in this area, but I did not find enough references (containing proofs). Is there any - for exactly this problem?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible to consider the exponential sequence?!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I start with the Zariski topology on the curve, then switch to analytic, so $\mathcal{O}_{C}$ is not the sheaf of regular functions anymore. Are the assumptions on $C$ necessary like smoothness? I would like to calculate the jacobian. Thank you!

Comment: The exponential sequence is of analytic nature. There is no exponential sequence for the Zariski topology and $\mathcal{O}_C$ must be the sheaf of holomorphic function (or continuous, or smooth functions). Otherwise there is no restriction on $C$, it may be any complex manifold, algebraic variety (even topological spaces if one consider instead the sheaf of continuous function, the only restriction being that $C$ must be locally simply connected, so that any non vanishing function has locally a logarithm).

Comment: As for the groups in the case of a smooth projective curve, the first tree terms are not interesting, it is : $0\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^*\rightarrow 0$. Moreover one has $H^2(C,\mathcal{O}_C)=0$, hence $H^2(C,\mathcal{O}_C^\times)=0$. So the most interesting part is $0\rightarrow H^1(C,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H^1(C,\mathcal{O}_C)\rightarrow Pic(C)\rightarrow H^2(C,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow 0$. We have $H^1(C,\mathbb{O}_C)\simeq\mathbb{C}^g$ (where $g$ is the genus), and $H^1(C,\mathbb{Z})\subset H^1(C,\mathcal{O}_C)$ is a lattice.

Comment: Hence the quotient $H^1(C,\mathcal{O}_C)/H^1(C,\mathbb{Z})$ is a torus called the Jacobian variety. This is the connected component of the Picard group.

Comment: @Roland Thank you. Do you know a reference for the proofs? For example $H^{1}(C,\mathcal{O}_{C}) \cong \mathbb{C}^{g}$?

Comment: @J224 This is just Serre duality : $H^0(C,\Omega_C)\simeq\mathbb{C}^g$ by definition of $g$ and $H^1(C,\mathcal{O}_C)$ is just the dual. Everything here is standard and covered in most book on Riemann surfaces, algebraic curves, complex geometry or algebraic geometry.